# How to schedule a request at a particular time?

Tags: python, simpy

I'm using simpy 3.xx with python 2.7.
I'm trying to build up a train simulation. What is needed is that the train process generated a request for entry at a specific time in the simulation. This must be very simple to do, but for sme reason I'm not able to find a solution.

Let's say at simulation-time 20 I want a process to generate a request event, how do I go about doing that? Normally I'd generate a request : req = res.request(), and then yield req. I wish to schedule a request event at a specific time.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code that you are writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with a `timeout`event. Here is a timeout event, based upon [the tutorial](http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/events.html?highlight=timeout). As you stated, this generates a request event at time 20.

```
#at time 20 generate a request event
import simpy
class TrainStation:
    def __init__(self,env):
        self.env= env
        self.request_event = env.event()
        self.request_receiver_process = env.process(self.receive_request())
        self.request_producer_process = env.process(self.produce_request())

    def produce_request(self):
        yield self.env.timeout(20)
        self.request_event.succeed()
        self.request_event = self.env.event()

    def receive_request(self):
        print("Waiting for request at time: {0}".format(env.now))
        yield self.request_event
        print("Request received at time: {0}".format(env.now))

env = simpy.Environment()
trainStation = TrainStation(env)
env.run()
```